# How to get my JS Popup Window to stay on top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, always-on-top

I have a website [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/admissions-toolbox.html).

When you open the site, after 2 seconds, you'll see some text in the background. This is part of a JavaScript Popup window. I am trying to get it to stay on top of everything else. It's set to come up automatically when someone arrives at the site. It simply displays updates I've made to the site.

As you can see, it's clearly no on top. It's a table popup. There's no z-index I can apply to it. The one thing I've tried that hasn't worked is.

```
<body onblur="self.focus();">
```

Is my jQuery getting in the way?

Comment: Why no z-index? Focus does a completely different thing. Z-index is the best solution. Maybe even the only one.

Comment: Where would I put it? I don't have this window tucked away in a stylesheet. Any styling is in-line. If I can use a z-index here, I'm not sure where.

Comment: inline is ok, add it to
<table .... style="... z-index: 50;"> ...

Comment: Why not you create a div for it? Make the div pop up, then use ('#mympopup').hide() on it.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Hang on.

Comment: Okay. Take a look at it now [Right Here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/admissions-toolbox.html) Now I just have to style it a bit better...

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing something a bit more CSS based...

**CSS...**

```
/*STYLES FOR CSS POPUP*/


#blanket {
   background-color:#111;
   opacity: 0.65;
   filter: alpha(opacity=65)
   *background:none;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 9001;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
}

#popUpDiv {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(images/background_img.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin-top: -200px; /* auto, centers horizontally and -120px is half your height to finish the centering vertically */
    border:5px solid #000;
    z-index: 9002;
}


#popUpDiv .close {
    background-image: url(images/x.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute; 
    top:10px; 
    right:10px
}
```

**HTML...**

```
<body onload="popup('popUpDiv')">

<div id="blanket" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none">

<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" class="close"><img src="images/x.png" /></a>
        <br />
    <h3 style="color: #FFF; padding-left: 10px;">Updates to the AR Toolbox</h3>
            <br />
                <br />
                <div style="width: 350px; height: 300px; text-align: left;">
                <p style="padding-left: 50px; color: #000;">• Check out some content here...</p>
                    <br />
                <p style="padding-left: 50px; color: #000;">• Check out some content here...</p>                
                    <br />
                <p style="padding-left: 50px; color: #000;">• Check out some content here...</p>
                    <br />
        </div>
</div>



<body onunload="javascript: exitpop()" >
```

**JavaScript...**

```
function toggle(div_id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
    else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}

function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
        blanket_height = viewportheight;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
        } else {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
    var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
    blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-200;//200 is half popup's height
    popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
}
function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
        window_width = viewportwidth;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
        } else {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
        }
    }
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    window_width=window_width/2-200;//200 is half popup's width
    popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
}
function popup(windowname) {
    blanket_size(windowname);
    window_pos(windowname);
    toggle('blanket');
    toggle(windowname);     

}
```

Once all this code is plugged in correctly, you'll get the centered popup on the page (onload) everytime the user re-freshes the page. HTML content can be placed in the popup which will add more usability.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/RHb6R/) (I've added images in the jsfiddle for looks. Change those out and you're good to go).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a plugin like fancybox?

http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Will fancybox allow for an onload event? or is it onclick only?